# required a bean of type 'org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisIndexedSessionRepository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-boot-starter

I have a project which uses spring boot which uses spring-boot-starter-data-redis to manage distributed session, which was running fine.

I tried to migrate to spring boot 3,  i was getting the below error.

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisIndexedSessionRepository' in your configuration
```

To fix the above error I have defined a bean as below.

```
 @Bean
 public RedisIndexedSessionRepository redisIndexedSessionRepository(RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate) {
        return new RedisIndexedSessionRepository(redisTemplate);
    }
```

After this a new error popped up as below.

```
 required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - redisIndexedSessionRepository: defined by method 'redisIndexedSessionRepository' in class path resource [com/google/ussm/config/UssmConfig.class]
    - sessionRepository: defined by method 'sessionRepository' in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]
```

To fix this error the below code came into handy.

```
 @Primary
    @Bean
    public RedisIndexedSessionRepository redisIndexedSessionRepository(RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate) {
        return new RedisIndexedSessionRepository(redisTemplate);
    }
```

---

Now the the application is running fine , but the `SessionExpiredEvent` and `SessionDeletedEvent` not being fired in the application.

Also I have noticed that in redis `:index:org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME` is missing , which constitutes the above problem.

Requesting any suggestion to fix this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Are you able to solve this issue?

Comment: IN spring boot 3 , they are not supporting Index based repository as it is not scalable.

Comment: @user7090887 i have added the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

There is support for **spring boot 3.2.0** for this.

Change **`@EnableRedisHttpSession`** to --->**`@EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession`**.
This change will configure **RedisIndexedSessionRepository** over **RedisSessionRepository** .

By using  `RedisIndexedSessionRepository` you can now start to listen to `SessionCreatedEvent`, `SessionDeletedEvent`, `SessionDestroyedEvent` and `SessionExpiredEvent` events.

For detailed explanation visit [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/configuration/redis.html#configuring-redisindexedsessionrepository).
For listening to Session Events visit [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/configuration/redis.html#listening-session-events).

---

And in your session security configuration.

add the below to save the sessions in the repository. Read more about [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#requireexplicitsave)

```
http.securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
                .requireExplicitSave(false)
        )
```